# Problema de sintaxe sql ao rodar migrate no ruby on rails(schema_migrations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tudo blz?
Estou com um problema ao tentar subir um aplicação em rails, quando rodo o comando `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
ele me da um erro de sintaxe ao criar a tabela schema_migrations.
Segue o erro:
**ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'string NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)' at line 1: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` string NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)**

Estou fazendo um update do ruby e do rails.
A versão atual são as seguintes:
Rails 5.2.6 e Ruby 2.5.8p224

**Na pasta initializer eu já possuo o arquivo **abstract_mysql2_adapter** que eu solicito o carregamento no enviroment.rb**

Conteúdo do **abstract_mysql2_adapter** :

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
  NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
end
```

E não possuo nenhuma migrate para essa tabela.

Versão das gems:

mysql2 (0.5.3)

Docker mysql image: mysql:5.6

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar na sua migration a nova versão do Active Record que é a mesma do Rails provavelmente: no exemplo abaixo adcionei a versão [5.2]

```rb
class AddEtniaPatients < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :patients, :etnia, "char(1)", after: :raca_cor
  end
end
```

Comment: Infelizmente não surtiu efeito, continuo com o mesmo erro e sem conseguir utilizar migrate ou seed pra popular o banco...

Comment: Eu adicionei 5.2 porem é a versão que eu atualizei. Você deve verificar para qual versão está sendo atualizado e fazer algo similar.

Comment: Entendi, mas essa table **schema_migrations**, está sendo criada automaticamente, não consigo controlar, o unico modo de "pular" essa tabela é criando manualmente ela no banco da forma correta(varchar)